# Can't call window service because args is too long?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I have a windows service. I call it with below method:

```
public static void StartService(string serviceName, string[] args)
{
     ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
     service.Start(args);
}
```

When my args[0] = "A long string, combine of a lot file name" I got error cannot start service: Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The stub received bad data.

Firstly, I think about access denied, but it isn't. If I change args[0] = "A short string, 1 folder path" then the service run successfully. Can anyone explain that for me?

Comment: What are the *actual* strings ("combine of a lot file name" is not helpful)? Also, what errors are occurring in the event logs?

Comment: Depends on what happens in `service.Start()`... Does that do any error logging? If not, we cannot answer this.

Comment: I got this error: Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The stub received bad data

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit in the number of characters that the command line can contain.

For the normal command line it's 8192 characters. For CreateProcess the limit is 32Kb.

References:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/10/56028.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473/en-us